# Positive/Negative Definite Functions Confusion

Tags: dynamical-systems, positive-definite, lyapunov-functions

I have the Lyapunov function $V(x_1,x_2) = x_1^2+x_2^2$ for the nonlinear system:

$$\dot{x_1} = x_2$$
$$\dot{x_2} = -x_1 - x_2-x_2^3$$

Now obviously $V$ is a positive definite function but in order to show asymptotic stability of the origin I need to show that $\dot{V} = \frac{\partial V}{\partial t}$ is negative definite. Or negative semi-definite which would then allow me to use LaSalle's invariance theorem.

So I found $\dot{V} = -2x_2^2-2x_2^4$ which I think is negative definite since it is $0$ @ $V(0)$ and it is strictly negative everywhere else. Now there is no information about the $x_1$ direction in $\dot{V}$ but can that change the result? The solution says that it is not locally negative definite. And I think the issue is that there is no $x_1$ information so how do we consider it when checking for definiteness?

Usually when I have a quadratic function as my Lyapunov function candidate I just use the fact:

$$V=x^T P x$$

and find the eigenvalues or leading principal minors of $P$. However, I cannot figure out a way to do that for this case. Is there a better way to check for definiteness of a function?

Comment: Your $\dot{V}$ is not negative definite, but only negative semi-definite, precisely because it is not strictly negative everywhere except the origin. Consider $x_1=1,x_2=0$. At this point you have $\dot{V}(1,0)=0$. Indeed you have $\dot{V}(x_1,0)=0$, independently of $x_1$ (as you correctly noted), so arbitrarily close to the origin the derivative of $V$ becomes zero along the line $x_2=0$. So it isn't even locally negative definite.

Comment: I understand and appreciate your input but I am trying to rely less on an intuitive way of looking for definiteness. For this situation in particular is there a way like finding the leading principal minors of the associated $P$ matrix. Essentially, a way I can get a surefire answer?

Comment: @AhsanYousaf in this case not because $\dot{V}(x)$ is not purely quadratic in $x$. You could look at it close to the origin by evaluating the Jacobian, but that could result to wrong conclusions about the global behavior. For example when $\dot{V}(x_1,x_2)=-x_2^2+\alpha\,x_1^4$.

Comment: @AhsanYousaf I can understand the desire for having some sort of algorithm (just like for checking stability), but as so often, in the general case, unfortunatly such a thing does not exist. There are however algorithms for special cases, like sum of square (sos) decompositons, which work for polynomials (so in this case as well). Generally, every variable must occure in the expression in question - so if you see that one or more variables are missing (like $x_1$ in this case), then the function cannot be negative (or positive) definite anymore, but semi-definite at best.

Comment: @SampleTime I see. Thank you for the explanation!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So you found
$$
\frac{d}{dt}(x_1^2+x_2^2)=-2x_2^2-2x_2^4=-x_2^2(1+2x_2^2)-\dot x_1x_2
$$
Now apply integration-by-parts to the last term to get
$$
\frac{d}{dt}(x_1^2+x_2^2+x_1x_2)
=-x_2^2(1+2x_2^2)+x_1\dot x_2
\\=-x_2^2(1+2x_2^2)-x_1^2-x_1x_2(1+x_2^2)
\\\le-x_1^2-x_2^2(1+2x_2^2)+\frac{x_1^2+x_2^2}2(1+x_2^2)
$$
which is negative outside the origin for $|x_2|<1$. Note that the modified quadratic form is still positive definite.

---

Remark: If you take the derivative of the second equation and insert the first one you get
$$
\ddot x_2+(1+3x_2^2)\dot x_2+x_2=0
$$
which is a Liénard equation and the trick above is standard there.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I'll make sure to keep this trick in mind.